# How to change the style of a div and reset it after 1000ms?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple (only 2 in this example) divs overlapping with each other...

What I'd like to do is to add buttons that represents each div, which when clicked, should increase their respective div's z-index for 1000ms only, in order to stay on top of all the other overlapping divs. This is the only purpose of the increase in z-index.

I was able to do some part of this, however, on second round of clicking, the secondary divs keep hiding behind the originally-on-top div.

Please check and run the snippet below:

```js
function increaseDivOne() {
    const box = document.getElementById('Div1');
    box.style.zIndex = '999';
    setTimeout(function () {
        box.style.zIndex = '1';
    }, 1000);
}
function increaseDivTwo() {
    const box = document.getElementById('Div2');
    box.style.zIndex = '999';
    setTimeout(function () {
        box.style.zIndex = '1';
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#Div1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#Div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increaseDivTwo()">Increase Div 2</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="increaseDivOne()">Increase Div 1</button>

<ul>Try this:</ul>
<li>Click "Increase Div 2"</li>
<li>Click "Increase Div 1"</li>
<li>Click "Increase Div 2" again and notice it will show up but will hide behind Div1 after 1s</li>
<p>My goal is to raise the z-index of a div for 1s, just enough to be on top of the other div and vice versa, but it should stay on top after the 1s set timeout. <br> Please note there's more Div in my actual project that will utilize this function.</p>
<div id="Div2">
  <h1>Div 2</h1>
</div>

<div id="Div1">
    <h1>Div 1</h1>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: _"Click "Increase Div 2" again and notice it will show up but will hide behind Div1 after 1s"_ - well isn't that what you wanted? You said you wanted to raise these elements to the front for 1 second, and then have them "sink back" to their original position, no?

Comment: _"should increase their respective div's z-index for 1000ms only"_, _"but it should stay on top after the 1s set timeout"_ - these two things appear to be contradicting each other? If you wanted it to stay on top, then what's the timeout for in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe sorry for the contradictions, anyways, my goal is: to temporarily increase the z-index of the selected div, just enough to raise it on top of the other divs. It's some sort of taskbar buttons to overlap other apps when selected. That's just what I thought of as a solution. But if there's a better way, I'd be happy to use it.

Comment: _Either_ you want to do it "temporarily", _or_ you want to _keep_ it in the raised state indefinitely. So which of the two is it now, actually? If you want to _keep_ it in that state - then why is there something being done after one second _at all_?

Comment: It's because the 999 z-index shouldn't stay there. I haven't mentioned that these windows/divs are draggable. When you click on one, it is automatically raised on top of other divs, just like how apps in a desktop usually works.

Comment: I think it would make much more sense, if you reset the z-index for all other divs, when you pull a new one "to the front", instead of trying to mess around with any timers here.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I'm just trying all options really for months now, still can't find a way to do this. There are libraries for this, but I prefer to not use them... Anyways thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in comments, I think it would be enough if you just reset the z-index for the currently on-top one, when a new one needs to be moved to the front - without any timers.

You could loop over all relevant div elements - or simply *remember* the previous one in a variable, and then reset z-index specifically for only that.

And then it would also be a bit nicer, if we did not manipulate inline styles for this, but simply set a class to apply the necessary z-index to the currently "active" element.

```js
var previous = null;
function increaseDiv(num) {
  if(previous) {
    previous.classList.remove('active');
  }
  var div = document.getElementById('Div'+num);
  div.classList.add('active');
  previous = div;
}
```

```css
#Div1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#Div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.active {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increaseDiv('2')">Increase Div 2</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="increaseDiv('1')">Increase Div 1</button>

<div id="Div2">
  <h1>Div 2</h1>
</div>

<div id="Div1">
    <h1>Div 1</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: One concern if I may ask, what if the id's for each divs doesn't aren't numerical like Div1, Div2?

Comment: Anyways, I've changed it to querySelector instead, and used class. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

if the divs got the same index, then the childnode order takes relay on priority of display, that's the problem here, to keep priority on the last div selected, you should then rewrite your function as the following :

```
function increaseDivOne() {
    const box = document.getElementById('Div1');
    box.style.zIndex = '999';
    setTimeout(function () {
       box.style.zIndex = '1';
       var elms=document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="Div"]:not(#Div1)');
       for (var p in elms) {
           elms[p].style.zIndex=-1;
       }
    }, 1000);
}
```